# Y-20 over Frankfurt

Tags: aircraft-identification

Saturday was a super clear day south of Frankfurt, Germany, near the airport (maybe 10 km away) and I saw a giant 4 engine plane flying over head - lit up by the sunset. It caught my eye because of the very broad wing, then with binoculars I could see it had a large red-ish oval strucure underneath it, a T-tail, and strut-like protusions on the wing bottoms. Googling silouettes afterwards I came to the conclusion it had to be a Chinese Y-20 but....

There are only like 20 of them operated by the PLA, and as there are no airshows going as far as I can tell, I am completely surprised. So the question is, why would it have been there? Or maybe I mistook it for something else?

I wasn't quick thinking enough to take a photo, though it would have been small and barely visible, it would have been something.

Comment: There are several transport aircraft with similar layout including C-5 Galaxy, C-17 Globemaster and Il-76. The last is notably operated by some civil operators as outsize cargo hauler.

Comment: You sure it wasn't an Emirates A380? Giant plane, red belly, and much more likely to be found at Frankfurt...

Comment: [Ramstein Air Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramstein_Air_Base), one of the largest US bases in Europe, is not too far away from Frankfurt. Probably it was a US military transporter (C-5, C-17).

Comment: Can you narrow down the time and location? That might allow finding the aircraft over on https://www.flightradar24.com/ (past 7 days are available free, longer history for subscribers only).

Comment: Sunset was approximately at 18:47 local time. Around that time an Emirates A380 passed over the airport enroute from London to Dubai, course west-northwest to east-southeast. But there are other candidates. Please add details such as time and location of spotting, observed course etc. to your question.

Comment: @MikeWise I'm also 10 km south of FRA (Gräfenhausen) and A380's fly over several times a day, typically (due to my location) on a south-eastward departure route. Are you a regular skywatcher in this area - would you know for sure that it wasn't an A380? Naturally I'm curious now too. :) I hope you solve it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From below, the Y-20 and C-17 are near identical.
[image]

Y-20 from https://nationalinterest.org/blog/reboot/chinas-y-20-real-china-military-plane-you-need-fear-185509
C-17 from https://www.aerotime.aero/28603-800-people-board-c-17-flying-out-of-overrun-kabul-airport

Ramstein AB (USAFE) being a short hop from Frankfurt, that would be the logical conclusion.

Comment: Yeah, somehow my Google-fu failed me 

Comment: @MikeWise probably because you included the word "red" it got resolved into "red China"

Comment: Also thinking the reddish-ness may have come from the sunset lighting, though it seemed to be painted on. What is that structure called? Seems like a lot of transports have it.

Comment: What 'structure'?

Comment: It's a possibility the aircraft was a C-17, but we don't know. That should be a comment until you have more information, like a reference form a ADS-B tracking site.

Comment: Good answer. You could probably improve it by selecting a C-17 image with a red stripe instead of a green one on the tail, by mentioning he other operators, or by pointing out that there's a lot of room for squadron colors. (examples: https://live.staticflickr.com/5161/5300236538_a412fec774_n.jpg , https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4262/35467031100_1cffa36bcf_b.jpg )

Comment: @MikeWise landing gear fairings? (I assume you are asking about the lumps the wheels are poking out of on the Y-20)